# Output of binaryRatingMatrix in r

Tags: r

I have created a matrix in Excel, of customers and items that have been purchased, by the customers. The column names are "Item 1", "Item 2" ... "Item n" and the row names are "Customer 1", "Customer 2", ... ,"Customer n".

The code is as follows:

```
library(recommenderlab)
setwd("C:\\Users\\amitai\\Desktop\\se")
USERBASE <- read.csv("USERBASE.csv")
USERBASE2 <- as(USERBASE,"binaryRatingMatrix")
rec <- Recommender(USERBASE2, method = "UBCF")
recommended.items.customer1 <- predict(rec, USERBASE2["customer 1",], n=5)
as(recommended.items.customer1, "list")
```

I expected to get a list of 5 items, which are most recommended to customer 1.
Instead, I got this output:

```
$`customer 1`
[1] "1"
```

After running the same code for customer 103, I got a similar output:

```
$`customer 103`
[1] "1"
```

My questions are as follows:

Is there a problem with the code I wrote?

Is there another action I should take after reading the CSV file?

How is the correct output supposed to look like?

Comment: hello and welcome to SO, what you want to achieve? and what is the problem?

Comment: I want to create a list of "n" recommended for each customer. My Excel file, is a table, which has items as columns, and customers as rows. If the customer, purchased the item, there is he value 1 in that cell. Otherwise, there is 0.

Comment: okay and what is you want to do with this excel file in R?

Comment: Try to create a list of recommended items to customers, based on the similarity between the purchases of the customers. In other words - Implementing user based collaborative filtering.

Comment: okay...can you provide some (test)data.

Comment: Do you mean an Excel file, in order to test ?

Comment: you can upload a excel file somewhere or use any other possibility to provide some data,  `dput()`  for example is also a nice for that